# How to define a return type of a function which contains another, no parameter, function in Swift?

Tags: ios, function, types, swift

How should I define the return type of createMyFunction in the following code in Swift?
Tried (() -> Int), but I get "Expression resolves to an unused function" error when I call createMyFunction() in Playground.

```
func createMyFunction() -> /*RETURN_TYPE_GOES_HERE*/ {

    func myFunction () -> Int{

        var number = 69
        return number
    }

}

createMyFunction();
```

Comment: just for the curiosity why you have defined a function within a function I mean myFunction() within createMyFunction()

Comment: Well, I'm only stripping the code so I can see how the things work at the basic level for the sake of learning.

Comment: Cool well you get your answer from @Antonio

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the correct way:

```
func createMyFunction() -> ( () -> Int ) {    
    func myFunction () -> Int{

        var number = 69
        return number
    }

    return myFunction
}
```

The return type is `() -> Int`: a closure taking no parameter and returning an `Int`.

In playground you see that error because the `createMyFunction` is returning a function, but you are not actually using it. You should try execute it immediately:

```
createMyFunction()()
```

Here `createMyFunction()` invokes the function returning another function. The 2nd set of parenthesis invokes the returned function.

Of course if you don't want to immediately invoke the returned function, you can assign it to a variable:

```
let myFunc = createMyFunction()
```

or pass it as a parameter to another function, etc.

Comment: Oh, I see, thank you. And what does this ()() syntax actually do?